# Zapier CLI convert errors when pushing and testing

Tags: command-line-interface, push, zapier, platform

I have started using Zapier Platform to make my app API available to Zapier users. I started with the Platform UI, and could create one trigger and one action, via the web interface, and it works just fine: I could create a "Zap" which sends me an email via Gmail when something happens in my app. The authentication type is 'session' and I could manage to retrieve my "access_token"  and pass it via bundle.authData.access_token to the triggers and actions.

I would now like to wrap other API functions and for that I would like to switch to the Zapier CLI.

I have installed zapier via NPM, could launch `zapier convert <ID> <DIR> --version 1.0.0`, and this has generated a project on my hard disk. All good so far.

I was expecting `zapier push` to make a new version 1.0.1 working like the 1.0.0, but I get an error message:

`Error: npm ERR! missing script: _zapier-build`

Also, when I try to run `zapier test`, I have this output looking like a test error (despite it's a warning, it seems to generate an error in the test set):

`1) should create an object (node:98545) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead.`

And when the tests try to call my app server, the authentication fails because the `Authorization` header, as received by the server, litterally is `Bearer {{bundle.authData.access_token}}` (so, the `access_token` has not been replaced with its real value by Zapier, I guess) (But when using the stuff built via the Zapier Platform UI works)

Could you please help me fix these errors?
Many thanks!

NB if it may help `zapier version` says:
`zapier-platform-cli/10.1.0 darwin-x64 node-v10.16.3`

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in CLI `10.1.0` that's been fixed in `10.1.1`.